# gsutil - always shows `no python2` message?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using `gsutil`(google cloud sdk) in `Amazon Linux 2018.03`. After install gsutil and configuration, I got a message always `which: no python2`

```
$ gsutil
which: no python2 in (/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sb
in:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/hom
e/ec2-user/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin)
```

How can I disable this warning?

Answer (score 2):

setting CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable worked for me.

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python
gsutil
```